# Graph API / FQL How to remove my own app from user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I gain offline_access from the user when he accepts my application. Now, in my website, the user can delete my access to his facebook account.
Is there a way, to tell facebook to remove my app from this user ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To revoke authorisation for an app, you can use a HTTP DELETE request with:

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/PROFILE_ID/permissions
```

From http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#permissions:

> You can de-authorize an application or revoke a specific extended permissions on behalf of a user by issuing an HTTP DELETE request to PROFILE_ID/permissions with a user access_token for that app.